# AWS 'Signature Does Not Match' error on completeMultipartUpload request

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using pre-signed urls to perform multipart uploads. I successfully create the multipart upload and upload all of the parts. But when I send the request to complete the multipart upload, I get a 'signature does not match' error. I am not sure if I am missing a header or something similar...that usually seems to be the cause of this error message.

I create my pre-signed url like this, it succeeds with no problems.

```js
const operation = 'completeMultipartUpload';
const params = {
  params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: filePath,
    Expires: this.expiration,
    UploadId: req.body.uploadId,
    MultipartUpload: {
      Parts: 
        [
          {
            ETag: XXX,
            PartNumber: X
          },
          {
            ETag: XXXX,
            PartNumber: XX
          }
        ]
    }
}



this.s3.getSignedUrl(operation, params, (err: AWS.AWSError, data: any) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
        res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
});
```

But when I POST to my pre-signed url, I get the signature does not match error.

```js
this.$http({
    url: presignedUrl,
    method: 'POST',
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error
})
```

Is there something else I need to include in this POST request?

Comment: The request body?

Comment: I already sent the request body to create the pre-signed url, do I need to send it again?

Comment: Creating a pre-signed URL doesn't "send" anything -- it just calculates the signature locally... so, yes.

Comment: I get the same error when I send the request with a body though, do the uploadId and parts need to be formatted differently from how I sent them to create the pre-signed url?

Comment: The body must match the body that is used to create the signature *exactly* -- and the SDK doesn't actually take a "body" -- it apparently just takes an object, and builds a request body for generating the signature (thrn discards the body).  Yours would need to be byte-for-byte identical to what the SDK generates.

Comment: Old post I know, but I ran into the same issue. Then I took a step back, and instead of fighting it, instead of using a presigned URL for the "complete" operation, I just do the complete multipart operation from my server side directly.  I was already passing in the list of completed parts, there's really nothing more to send from the device/UI in the last step.